# Как найти значение выражения с шагом h?

Tags: c++, математика

Вычислить значения функции в диапазоне [, ] c шагом ℎ. Если функция
не определена, вывести сообщение типа «Деление на ноль», «Логарифм из не положительного
числа», «Корень из отрицательного числа»:sqrt(*x − 1) /ln(2 − 8)
Вот мой код:

```
//вычислить значения функции в диапащоне [a,b] c шагом h
 #include<iostream>
 #include<math.h>
 using namespace std;

int main() 
{
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
     float a, b, h;
     //ввод данных
         cout << "a=";
     cin >> a;
     cout << "b=";
     cin >> b;
     cout << "h=";
     cin >> h;
     //проверка корректности или замена:
         if (a > b) swap(a, b);
     for (float x = a; x < b + h; x += h) //цикл [a,b]
     {
         if (x < 1) cout << "Корень из отрицательного числа\n";
         else if (x == 2) cout << "Деление на ноль\n";
         else if (x == 4) cout << "Логарифм не положительного числа\n";
         else 
        {
             float y = sqrt(x*x - 1) / log(2*x - 8);
             cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; //вывод
            
        }
    }
     return 0;
    }
```

Товарищи знающие,что тут не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (float x = a; x < b + h; x += h)
```

у вас цикл от `a` до `b`, а не до `b + h`, зачем вы его воткнули то?

```
if (x < 1) cout << "Корень из отрицательного числа\n";
```

у вас вообще-то в уравнении `sqrt(x^2 - 1)` и квадрат отрицательного числа - это положительное число, а проверять надо `x^2 - 1 < 0`

```
else if (x == 4) cout << "Логарифм не положительного числа\n";
```

а почему равенство строгое? При `x < 4` логарифм положительный что ли?

А еще угадайте, что происходит при x = 4,5 и почему

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошо,а остальные две проверки верные?@Zhihar

Comment: @Юрий - ни одной проверки не правильно :)

Comment: Деление на ноль происходит при x= 4.5 @Zhihar

Comment: @Юрий и где это у вас в коде? у вас там почему-то стоит `x == 2`

Comment: Я сначала подумал про 2,но потом по вашему графику увидел что был не прав.@Zhihar

Comment: @Юрий, а без графика `log(x) = 0` при каком условии? когда `x = 1`, т.е. `2x - 8 = 1`

Comment: Хорошо,теперь при исправлении всё правильно.Спасибо вам за помощь:)

Comment: @Юрий, радуйтесь, что функция простая - с той же `sin(x) / x` и ей подобным пришлось бы помучаться :))))))